# Hide directory name from URL by .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When user types:

```
www.domain.com/standard/Public/Modules/home.php or 
www.domain.com/standard/Public/Modules/contacts.php
```

(or anything that follows the same pattern)

I want the URL to be displayed like this:

```
www.domain.com/home
www.domain.com/contacts
...
```

My current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule    ^home.php/?$   standard/Public/Modules/home.php  [NC,L] 
RewriteRule    ^contacts.php/?$   standard/Public/Modules/contacts.php  [NC,L]
```

Comment: Normally this is not achieved with redirects, but instead by using what is known as a [Front Controller Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern), where you can define your routes from the outset to call specific pieces of code. I like to use [Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com/) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have this in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /standard/Public/Modules/login\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^standard/Public/Modules/login\.php$ /home [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /standard/Public/Modules/logout\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^standard/Public/Modules/logout\.php$ /contacts [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^home/?$ /standard/Public/Modules/login.php  [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^contacts/?$ /standard/Public/Modules/logout.php  [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hi @anubhava, it still doesn't work, should I put .htaccess file in Modules folder? also I had a mistake in the last code section, now its correct.

Comment: Do you already have `/standard/Public/Modules/.htaccess` file?

Comment: My .htaccess file is currently in /standard/  folder, I guess I should move it to Modules folder, right ?

Comment: No it needs to be in the parent directory of `standard`

Comment: No you didn't read what I wrote. `it needs to be in the parent directory of standard`

Comment: Right, sorry I misunderstood what you have written. Thank you, now it works though I lost my css connection.

Comment: For css/js just make sure you use absolute URLs i.e. starting with `/` or `http://`

Answer (score 1):

I use this, no need to individually set rewrites for pages

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Comment: Never mind. Re-read the question and realised this isnt what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On                         

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)-product(.*).html$ /products/view/$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)-cat(.*).html$ /products/listing/$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^products.html$ /products/listing/ [L]
    RewriteRule ^bioproducts.html$ /products/bio_listing/ [L]
    RewriteRule ^aboutus.html$ /static/index/15 [L]
    RewriteRule ^contacts.html$ /static/contacts [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)-partners(.*).html /partners/index/$2 [L]



</IfModule>
```